# HTML Yahoo Mail background color issue

Tags: html, css, email, yahoo

So I was working on an html email that works across all emails, and everything works with the exception of one thing: The background color doesn't show up in yahoo mail (tested in chrome). Optimally, the linear gradient would work in yahoo mail, but that isn't showing up. I know for HTML emails the format should be a table, but the format is working in this instance. I also know that everything should be inline, I just put the code in putmail to move everything inline. Attached is a link to the full HTML/CSS code. If you guys could let me know why yahoo isn't displaying the background color or linear gradient, that would be great. Thanks :) 
HTML

```
<body style="background-color: #bae1eb">
<div id="image_container">
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/go1ytzr7dogudlf/cloudlogologo.png?dl=0" alt="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/go1ytzr7dogudlf/cloudlogologo.png?dl=0" id="image">
</div>
<div id="mainBody">
    <div id="textBody">
        <p> Dear Person, </p>
        <p> Welcome to join the TUTUroomii community. Here, you can explore amazing people and housing resources in the LGBTQ+ community. We hope you will find your ideal roomie, new friends, and even more by using the APP. Have Fun!</p>
        <p> Cheers, </p>
        <div id="endingp">
            <p id="exception"> For a better </p>
            <img id="end_logo" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/x7yxpmzj4cpcgdt/forabetter.png?dl=0" alt="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/x7yxpmzj4cpcgdt/forabetter.png?dl=0">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="social-icons-container">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/TUTUroomii"><img class="social-icons" id="twitter" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/cpgk8dj48niiwjf/twitter.png?dl=0" alt="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/cpgk8dj48niiwjf/twitter.png?dl=0"></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/tuturoomii/"><img class="social-icons" id="instagram" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/bp2iyt1rnn89aoc/instagram.png?dl=0" alt="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/bp2iyt1rnn89aoc/instagram.png?dl=0"></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/tuturoomii/?fref=ts"><img class="social-icons" id="facebook" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/ps2y270i0s6csam/facebook.png?dl=0" alt="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/ps2y270i0s6csam/facebook.png?dl=0"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="footerText">
        <p class="center">If you wish to unsubscribe,</p>
        <a href="" target="_blank" style="color:#7D6796">
            <p class="center">unsubscribe here </p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footerFooter">
</div>
```

CSS

```
body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 99%;
}

body {
    /* For WebKit (Safari, Google Chrome etc) */
    background: #bae1eb;
    background-color: #bae1eb;
    /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#bae1eb, white) center center no-repeat;
    /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#bae1eb, white) center center no-repeat;
    /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#bae1eb, white) center center no-repeat;
    /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#bae1eb, white) center center no-repeat;
    /* Standard syntax */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
p {
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

h1 {
    color: #898989;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

p {
    color: #898989;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.fullwidth {
    width: 100%;
}

#image {
    display: block;
    width: 175px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#image_container {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#mainBody {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: white;
    width: 350px;
    height: auto;
}

#textBody {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 3em;
    width: 80%;
}

#end_logo {
    width: 10em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#exception {
    display: inline-block;
}

#social-icons-container {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.social-icons {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

#instagram {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#social-icons-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#footerText {
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

#footerFooter {
    margin-top: 25px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: For my non-professional view, it may be security or performance reason. Also, it may be some settings inside the email (something like "Don't show the pictures") in the Google mail.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question but I ran into this exact issue today. As far as I can tell, reading up on everything I could find (tutorial forums etc.) and inspecting HTML emails sent to my yahoo address, linear-gradient backgrounds are not supported at all for yahoo HTML emails. The examples I could access all used images in place of pure css backgrounds. Or they simply avoided using gradient backgrounds entirely opting instead for a flat design.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following attribute:

```
<body bgcolor="#bae1eb"
```

[Also this article,  may be will be useful for you](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/9_ways_to_prevent_yahoo_headaches)

Answer (score 0):

This does work on Yahoo https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-background-color/

However, because you've put it on the `<body>` tag, it won't show. That's because Yahoo, like many other email clients, changes the `<body>` tag. Specifically, Yahoo will remove all styles on it (many others just change it from body to div).

Best solution is to put this on a div inside the `<body>` instead.

Linear-gradient is not supported: https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-linear-gradient/